# what is the API (REST) to find out whether bare metal server provisioned or not?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

According to  SLDn of softlayer Softlayer_hardware/some id/getObjects?mask with domain name and Vm name will give provision status.But when I make RESt call with same I get 200 ok but xml output hass error.

```
Please let me know how can I get VM provision successful or not? Help me with REST API.

 https://userid:apikey@api.softlayer.com/sldn/rest/SoftLayer_Hardware/****/getObject?mask=[hostName,domain]

* is ID which got when we made below rest call

https://userid:apikey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware.json

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Service does not exist</faultstring>
 </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following requests to get information of Virtual Guest/Hardware already provisioned:

**Virtual Guest:**

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[VSI_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,createDate,provisionDate,activeTransaction,activeTransactionCount,status]

Method: GET
```

**Hardware:**

```
https://[username]:[apikey @api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware/[Hardware_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,provisionDate,hardwareStatus,lastTransaction]

Method: GET
```

or

```
https://[username]:[apikey @api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/[Hardware_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,provisionDate,activeTransaction,activeTransactionCount,hardwareStatus]
```

**Where:**

To know that a Server is already provisioned, please review that:

- “activeTransaction” is NULL, or
- “provisionDate” has a value different to NULL (i.e. when the VSI is ready, the provisionDate will have the respective provisionDate)
- The “status” is Active

To get VSI/Hardware ids, please review:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests

**Some References:**

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/getObject
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getObject
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest
>   https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest